# c++ initialize values static int with CLI array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static, command-line-interface

So I have 2 arrays both are 2 dimensional cli::arrays.
What's the right syntax to initialize an cli::array. I tried in the example below but that doesnt work.

```
//Cords.h
ref class Cords {
private:
     static array<int,2>^ Xcord = gcnew array<int,2>(4,4);  // [4][4]
     static array<int,2>^ Ycord = gcnew array<int,2>(4,4);  // [4][4]
public:
     Cords();
     static int getX(void);
     static int getY(void);
};
int Cords::Xcord[0][0] = 4234; //On these lines is the mistake
int Cords::Ycord[0][0] = 2342; //On these lines is the mistake
```

Comment: .NET arrays are always initialized to zero.  You can use a "type initializer" to preload other values.

Comment: could you show an example?

Comment: See the example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx#BKMK_Static_constructors

Comment: @saito , do not static fields private,and  to bear this field in a different scope(area). And remove the int before assignment value to variables.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem with a static constructor and I noticed that you are supposed to type [0,0] instead of [0][0]. I'm used to normal C arrays.

```
//Cords.h
ref class Cords {
private:
static array<int,2>^ Xcord = gcnew array<int,2>(4,4);  // [4][4]
static array<int,2>^ Ycord = gcnew array<int,2>(4,4);  // [4][4]
static Cords() {         //static constructor to initialize values
      Xcord[0,0] = 4234; // [0,0] instead of [0][0]
      Ycord[0,0] = 2342;
      ...
    }
public:
     Cords();
     static int getX(void);
     static int getY(void);
};
```